How can I add the bibliography to the references with bibLatex?
Disclaimer: I have no Idea about anything i just copy from the internet.
I have looked around a bit to find out how but I couldnt find a solution that works. I am using MikTex with the TexWorks editor.
I think that the minimal code looks like this:
\documentclass[ngerman, a4paper, fontsize=12pt, bibliography=totocnumbered, headings=small, parskip=half]{scrreprt}

 %% Language and font encodings
 \usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
 
  %% Bibliography
 \usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, isbn=true, maxbibnames=5, sorting=none]{biblatex}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \addbibresource{Quellen/QuellenV1.bib}
 
\begin{document}

\cite{No1}
\cite{No2}
\chapter*{Literaturverzeichnis}
\nocite{*}
 \printbibliography
 
 \end{document}

The .bib file looks like this:
% This file was created with Citavi 6.19.0.0

@misc{No1,
 editor = {123},
 year = {1234},
 title = {1234},
 url = {123},
 address = {1234},
 edition = {3}
}


@misc{No2,
 editor = {123},
 year = {123},
 title = {123},
 url = {123},
 address = {123},
 edition = {5}
}

I have been told that i need to compile multiple times, so far i tried copying different orders from different threads: PdfLatex + BibTex + PdfLatex + PdfLatex; PdfLatex + Biber + PdfLatex + PdfLatex; Xelatex + BibTex + PdfLatex + Xelatex;
Stressing the fact that i tried when i try to compile with biber nothing happens, when i try to compile with BibTex it says that is didnt find \citation commands, i didnt find a \bibdata command and it didnt find a \bibstyle command.
I cant find any of these three commands in the biblatex documentation so i have no ider what to do.

Using PDFLaTeX, Biber, PDFLaTeX, PDFLaTeX should work and does if I test your code. If it doesn't please show the blg file and the log file. Running bibtex does not make sense when using backend=biber (or when removing backend=biber, because it is the default). BTW: For first tests, I always recommend to put all files in the same directory and not use subdirectories, e.g., for the bib file.

I guess i didnt trust the Biber compiling so i interrupted it and it never worked, now it does work so i will close the question.
